# Why in this code these variables aren't changed in batch?

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, debugging, asynchronous

Variable flagForTest is false and variable count is 10 but they should be: true and 100. Debugs in batch show correct values, debugs in test class or invoked in Anonymous Apex show incorrect values. How can I take values from batch to Apex class?

This is my test class:

```
@isTest(seeAllData = true) private class PatchPanelTriggerClassTest {


  @isTest private static void deleteDuplicatesTest() {

    PatchPanelTriggerClassTestBatch p = new PatchPanelTriggerClassTestBatch();

    Test.startTest();
    Database.executeBatch(p, 200);
    System.debug('p.flagForTest = ' + p.flagForTest);  // false - incorrect, should be true
    Test.stopTest();

    System.debug('p.flagForTest = ' + p.flagForTest); // false - incorrect, should be true
    System.debug('PatchPanelTriggerClassTestBatch.count= ' + p.count); // 10 - incorrect, should be 100
  }
}
```

And this is code for my batch:

```
global with sharing class PatchPanelTriggerClassTestBatch implements Database.batchable<SObject> {

public Boolean flagForTest = false;
public  Integer count = 10; 

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext param1, List<Patch_Panel__c> param2) {
    flagForTest = true; // why it show false in test class and Anonymous Apex?
    count = 100; // why it show 10 in test class and Anonymous Apex?

    for (Patch_Panel__c p : param2) {
        System.debug(p.Name); // debugs are correct
    }

    System.debug('flagForTest in batch ' +  flagForTest); // here is true - correct
    System.debug('PatchPanelTriggerClassTestBatch.count in batch  = ' + count); // 100 - correct
    System.debug('Batch execute ends');
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext param1) {
    System.debug('nothing here');
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext param1) {
    flagForTest = true;
    String s = 'select Name, Total_No_of_Ports__c from Patch_Panel__c limit 160'; // 

    return Database.getQueryLocator(s);
}
```

}

Comment: Because have just initialized the batch class's object and your expected values are being set in the execute method. Also, these are not available outside of the batch chunks context.

Comment: I've linked an answer that should satisfy your question. If it does not, please [edit] your question to include additional information, and then let us know, and we'll be glad to reopen it for you.